# What rights does a songwriter have when a song is made out as a youtube video by another artist?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, music

I have given permission for another artist to record a song that I have written and that song will also have a video which will most likely go on youtube. 
What are a songwriter's rights in terms of youtube revenue no matter how small ?

Comment: What did the permission given to the other artist specify?

Comment: There isn't any document as it stands. I wrote the song basically for the artist to perform ensuring that due credit is given to the copyright holder (Whilst duly registered with the relevant PRO)once the song is ready to be distributed.I guess because everything has happened out of friendship we didn't have the immediate requirement to lay things out clearly.However, now  there is a need to adhere to set rules and standards as much as we can.

Comment: @lacoder the rule is that you negotiate a deal. There's no standard. It's completely between the two of you.

Answer (score 4):

When you license your IP (like a song) you can specify the terms and conditions of its use by the licensee, including revenue shares from any derived work.

However, if, as your comment suggests, you grant an "informal" license, and later decide that you want to "firm things up" with a license having different terms, that's a matter you would have to either negotiate or litigate with your counterparty.

If you want a common reference point for negotiation of this sort of license, you might have a look at [compulsory license terms](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/14716/10).

Comment: There's nothing here to litigate - having gifted the licence you can't demand it back.

Comment: @DaleM - The implication was that the *terms* of the "informal" license were unclear or ambiguous.  If the parties disagree on what the terms of the agreement were, the worst (legal) case for resolving the dispute is to "discover" the terms through litigation.