# I want to have someone cover a song for a documentary. What are the steps?

Tags: copyright, regulations

I am producing a documentary based on the Native American Culture and I want to have a Native Singer cover a pop song, written by Sia.  What are the steps?  It is just going to be used for the documentary only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will using a cover of a song in a film free me from legal obligations?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/will-using-a-cover-of-a-song-in-a-film-free-me-from-legal-obligations)

Answer (score -1):

The song is protected by copyright, which means that you need a license, specifically a "mechanical license". The law does not specify how you do this, just that this is what you need to do. [This](https://www.tunecore.com/cover-song-licensing) is a randomly selected business that might do this.

Comment: no, this is affixing the song to a motion picture, that requires a synchronization license.